# Beamer, booktabs, empheq, pgfplots incompatability

Tags: beamer, pgfplots, booktabs, empheq

The following minimal example

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Test
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

gives the error

/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduledecorations
.code.tex:31: No room for a new \dimen .
\ch@ck ...\else \errmessage {No room for a new #3}
                                                  \fi 
l.31 ...\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentremainingdistance

This error is not produced if beamer or one of the three packages is not used.  The relevant file list is:

- beamer.cls    2013/12/02 3.33 A class for typesetting presentations (rcs-revision 332bfd3ce558)
- booktabs.sty    2005/04/14 v1.61803 publication quality tables
- empheq.sty    2014/07/16 v2.14 Emphasizing equations
- pgfplots.sty    2014/08/04 v1.11 Data Visualization (1.11-3-g4c99d7a)

Does anyone know of a workaround?

Comment: Try with `\usepackage{etex}` before all? However probably `empheq` can be replaced with `tcolorbox` etc. ?